# 95 blazer evap can purge solenoid valve to evap purge pressure switch valve

Tags: engine, chevrolet, blazer, evap, purge-solenoid

Reassembling evap purge solenoid valve to evap purge pressure switch valve any pics or websites that can help. Camera on phone doesn't work. Need visual aid to reassemble
 Help please .

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this helps; best I could find...

[image]

Comment: Yes it did thank you I at first wasn't sure the proper name of the part in question but later was able to find out and ask for its location.